# iOS: Efficient drawing of multiple independent lines

Tags: objective-c, ios, graphics, line

I need to draw multiple, non-connected, lines in an UIView's drawRect method. I could only find "CGContextAddLines" method but this connects the line end points.
Is there a method in iOS to draw multiple lines which are not connected? I want to draw the lines on the fly, so I do not need caching in a buffer.

Regards,

Comment: I think you need CGPathAddLines

Comment: @phix23 The docs say `CGPathAddLines` "adds a sequence of connected line segments to a path," so I don't think that's what the OP wants. However, you could just do `CGPathMoveToPoint(); CGPathAddLineToPoint();` repeatedly.

Comment: At the moment I am using CGPathMoveToPoint() in a loop but I thought that there might be a more optimized way to draw lines (similar to Canvas.drawLines in Android for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question was asked a long time ago... but the way that I do this is with
`CGContextStrokeLineSegments(context, points, numPoints);`
If you create an array of CGPoints that contains the start and end point for each line segment and pass it in to the function, it will draw lines for each set of two CGPoints i.e. a line between points[0] and points[1], a line between points[2] and points[3] etc.... If you need to draw more complicated curves, you can always overlap the points as well to connect the line segments.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep this in mind for the next projects where I need it.